# how to get jdk version from the download string in bash script

Tags: bash, ansible

I have the below download sting

```
javaurl=http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u131-b11/d54c1d3a095b4ff2b6607d096fa80163/jdk-8u131-linux-x
64.tar.gz
```

I want to get jdk-8u131-linux-x64.tar.gz  so that I can do tar -xvzf on it

so I tried

```
echo `expr match "$javaurl" '\(.[jdk]*.tar.gz\)'`
```

but I did not find it

I tried in ansible

```
name: Download Java to Latest Version
      shell: |
              mkdir /opt/java
              cd /opt/java
              wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" {{javaurl}}
              tar -xzvf "{{{javaurl##*/}}}"
```

but it throwing error

```
"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected char '#' at 130. String: mkdir /opt/java\ncd /opt/java\nwget -c --header \"Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie\" {{javaurl}}\ntar -xzvf \"{{{javaurl##*/}}}\"\n"}
```

Comment: Did you try `.*(jdk.*)\.tar\.gz`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo "${javaurl##*/}"` should work. It will remove everything upto the last slash and that points to your file name.

Comment: thank you for your comment but my shell script is not working in ansible

Comment: shell: |
              mkdir /opt/java
              cd /opt/java
              wget -c --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" {{javaurl}}
              tar -xzvf "{{{javaurl##*/}}}"

Comment: Can't you use `${var}` syntax in ansible ? As a quick hack you could try `tar -xzvf "$(echo ${javaurl##*/})"` to try and get the var from a subshell if it doesn't, but not sure since i haven't used ansible.

Comment: Or just use a globstar `tar -xzvf ./jdk-*.tar.gz` assuming only a single jdk tar exists